# Count data with one factor level containing only zeroes

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I have a simple poisson glm with one predictor that has three levels. Unfortunately, for one level my response, the variable has only counts of zero. I expected very low counts (perhaps a one or a two at most). Because of one level having all zeros, neither my poisson glm, nor "zeroinfl" (from pscl), work. The glm throws out a massive standard error for the all zero factor level and the zeroinfl gives me an error message.

Is there a statistical way to say that the other two groups are different from the one with all zeros?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems abandoned and OP is not longer on site to answer necessary followup questions

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen This question can quite happily be closed. Is that something I should have done myself? I left it open in the hopes that someone would have an answer for me. Honestly, though, I had given up on ever getting any response. I am around, but had forgotten that I had this account. Recently I have been using a different one.

Comment: Please merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]).

Comment: I suspect this is answerable. Can you post a small example dataset?

Comment: I will go merge my accounts. I didn't know that was possible.
I can't remember which data set I wanted to ask about 4 years ago, but it is something that crops up quite a lot. I'll have a look when I get to work tomorrow.